# Transferring values between two different angular2 components?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

**The design:**

We have, two angular 2 components, say CompA and CompB. When the HTML of CompB is initialized, CompA should get automatically initialized. There are values (public) in CompB that we want to use in CompA. Also, we have dependency injected CompA in CompB.

**The issue:**

I see a lot of documentation using "@output" tag and "Emitter", but I am able to access the public variable, say V1 in CompB simply by CompA.V1. 
This solves the problem.

*But is this even allowed? Why does no documentation talk about it? Is this a safe way of accessing sensitive information?*

Comment: you should use `@Input` and `@Output` variables only.

Answer (score 2):

Why you need such pattern to init a component with another component?
If the requirement is only to get access of other properties then you can use the following snippet.

**A Component**

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit {
  testProperty: any[] = [5, 4, { id: 34 }, false];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('a init');
  }

}
```

**B Component**

```
import { AComponent } from '../a/a.component';
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
  componentRef:AComponent;
  constructor() { 
    this.componentRef = new AComponent();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.componentRef.testProperty);
    this.componentRef.ngOnInit();
  }

}
```

Comment: The design requires CompA to get initialized when the HTML of compB is initialized. I'll explain it further. 
There is a common set of code that is put in CompA, which is used on several occasions. To reduce duplications, the HTML and its corresponding service and component are pulled out to a separate reusable piece. Now, this reusable piece is called from the ngOnInit of the CompB. @Ashrafil Islam